# SQL query for Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to write a query from one table name 't'. It has mainly 4 columns involved in my query. From this sample data, I need a specific output.

```
Unit_name      Unit_id_from   unit_transferred_to     Action
------------------------------------------------------------
UNITABC        011102X         0215478Y               CONVERTED  
UNITQWE        0222487Y        NULL                   NEW RAISED   
UNITASDF       0215478Y        NULL                   INVALID   
UNITPOU        0487985Z        08975469K              CONVERTED  
UNITHUT        08975469K       NULL                   INACTIVE
```

The name of unit_transferred_to is actually in first column unit_name. So I need name of the unit_transferred_to from unit_name and the action = 'converted'

The output needs to look like this:

```
Unit_name   Unit_id_from   unit_transferred_to     unit_transfer_name     Action
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UNITABC       011102X        0215478Y              UNITASDF               CONVERTED  
UNITPOU       0487985Z       08975469K             UNITHUT                CONVERTED
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a `join`:

```
select ti.Unit_name, ti.Unit_id_from, ti.unit_transferred_to,
       tito.unit_name as unit_transfer_name, 
       ti.Action
from ti join
     ti tito
     on ti.unit_transferred_to = tito.unit_transferred_from
where ti.action = 'CONVERTED'
```

Comment: there is no column named unit_transfer_name in table t.. i want to alias unit_name as   two column in my output  one is for unit_name as unit_name_from and unit_name as unit_name transferred_to.. It has to done by join but i am not getting it correctly